# Find whether Ola/Uber/Lyft service is available or not in users location in iOS and Android App

Tags: android, ios, swift, deep-linking, uber-api

In my iOS and Android app using universal link(Deep Link) I am taking user from my app to Ola, Uber and Lyft app to book cab with source and destination location pre filled, it is working fine  but I want to show or hide the Cab Provider based on whether they provide service in users location or not. For Ex: Lyft is not available outside US and Canada, so if a user from India opens my app I should show only Uber, Ola and hide Lyft. I don't see any API in their developer site which provides list of countries they provide service to.How to approach this?

Comment: Can't you just check if the app is installed with UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url)?

Comment: What If I just landed in India from the USA and open Lyft? @Andrea

Comment: you are right! didn't thought about that :-D

Comment: Also, whether the app is installed or not we will be showing the cab service provider button if they provide service in users location, on selecting the button we are taking the user to Appstore or Playstore to let them install the app if it is not already installed